# Meteor hangs on installing Meteor tools

Tags: meteor

I am having an issue when trying to run meteor projects with version code  < METEOR@2.13.
I am able to create and run a new project with no issues. I have tried the following commands with no success:

`meteor update`
`meteor reset`
`meteor update --all-packages`

All the above commands fail with the following error:

```
/Users/[username]/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.13.0.yk4rw8.bheh++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:218
      throw error;
      ^

Error: incorrect data check
    at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] (zlib.js:187:17)
 => awaited here:
    at Promise.await (/Users/[username]/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.13.0.yk4rw8.bheh++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:60:12)
    at Object.extractTarGz (/Users/[username]/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.13.0.yk4rw8.bheh++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fs/tools/fs/files.ts:791:11)
    at Object.exports._extractAndConvert (/tools/packaging/tropohouse.js:47:9)
    at /tools/packaging/tropohouse.js:502:42
    at Object.enterJob (/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:388:12)
    at /tools/packaging/tropohouse.js:499:24
    at Function.each (/Users/[username]/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.13.0.yk4rw8.bheh++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore-node-f-pre.js:1316:7)
    at /tools/packaging/tropohouse.js:466:11
    at Object.enterJob (/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:388:12)
    at Object.download (/tools/packaging/tropohouse.js:424:20)
    at /tools/packaging/tropohouse.js:597:22
    at Object.enterJob (/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:388:12)
    at exports.Tropohouse.downloadPackagesMissingFromMap (/tools/packaging/tropohouse.js:594:20)
    at /tools/cli/main.js:469:28
    at /tools/packaging/catalog/catalog.js:100:5
    at Object.capture (/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:283:5)
    at Object.catalog.runAndRetryWithRefreshIfHelpful (/tools/packaging/catalog/catalog.js:99:31)
    at /tools/cli/main.js:468:15
    at Object.capture (/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:283:5)
    at /tools/cli/main.js:465:33
    at Console.withProgressDisplayVisible (/tools/console/console.js:639:14)
    at springboard (/tools/cli/main.js:464:11)
    at /tools/cli/main.js:1165:7 {
  errno: -3,
  code: 'Z_DATA_ERROR'
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this by installing a lower version of Meteor. It turns out that when you install Meteor, it targets the latest version, which might not work with a previous version of the project, in my case 2.12 failed to run on 2.13. My project was running Meteor 2.12, yet it failed to work with `Meteor Tool` version 2.13.

To resolve this, I installed an older version of Meteor using the following command:

`curl "https://install.meteor.com/?release=1.9" | sh`

This allowed me to match the Meteor version with the appropriate Meteor Tool version and resolve the compatibility issue. If you're facing a similar problem, consider installing a version of Meteor that aligns with your project's requirements. Keep in mind that this solution might vary depending on your specific situation.